# How to sum values of nested dictionaries in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I want to add only the price values to know the total of the shopping list

```
shopping_list = {
    "product1": {
        "product_name": "milk",
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 2},

    "product2": {
        "product_name": "butter",
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 3}
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `sum([shopping_list[key]["price"] for key in shopping_list.keys()])`

Comment: ...or `sum([prods["price"] for prods in shopping_list.values()])` ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
shopping_list = {
    "product1": {
        "product_name": "milk",
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 2},

    "product2": {
        "product_name": "butter",
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 3}
}

total_price = 0
for key in shopping_list.keys():
    total_price += shopping_list[key]["price"]

print(total_price)
```

Comment: `sum` is a Python builtin.  You should avoid using it as a variable name.